# Error in password decryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have to store the password field in SQL Server database in an encrypted format and I have to decrypt it while the user is logging into the system. The encryption part is working fine. But I am getting the error in decryption part as "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array" at the line

```
byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd);
```

of decryption module.

```
private string Encryptdata(string password)
{
        string encryptpwd = string.Empty;
        byte[] encode = new byte[password.Length];
        encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        encryptpwd = Convert.ToBase64String(encode);
        return encryptpwd;
}

private string Decryptdata(string encryptpwd)
{
        string decryptpwd = string.Empty;
        UTF8Encoding encodepwd = new UTF8Encoding();
        Decoder Decode = encodepwd.GetDecoder();
        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd); //here I am getting error as "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array"
        int charCount = Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        decryptpwd = new String(decoded_char);
        return decryptpwd;
}
```

Input Data: `prabu`
Encrypted Data: `cHJhYnU=`

Comment: You are not Encrypting at all... Encoding is just about ANSI/UTF8/... representations.

Comment: And this code works well. No error. Are you sure you call Decryptdata method with "cHJhYnU=" parameter?

Comment: I suggest you look into [one way hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification) of the passwords, leaving the code able to decrypt the password allows any attacker to do so too.

Comment: Please, please, please read the following: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: As every one already suggested, Use an irreversible encrypting/hashing algorithm such as md5, and when the user try to log in, Encrypt the attempt password and compare it with the stored encrypted password.

Comment: No error found in your code . Please check the value of string while passing.prabu R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error because your code is like this:

```
    string password = "prabu";
    string encryptdata = Encryptdata(password);
    string decryptdata = Decryptdata(password);
```

Comment: obviously in the code, that he didn't show to us. It's my assumption based on runing his code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving encrypted the user password and decrypting it to perform the authentication, we use save the passwords as salted hashes, where the salt is auto generated each time a new password is to be stored (the salt and hash are stored in the database).

To authenticate a login attempt, we generate a hash for the password provided during the login, but use the salt which we stored when the password was initially set. Then to authenticate the login, simply compare the two hash values.

For example, if you choose the SHA1 hash function:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public interface ISaltedHash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the hash.
    /// </summary>
    string Hash
    {
        get;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the salt.
    /// </summary>
    string Salt
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class SaltedHashProvider
{
    #region Fields

    private int m_saltLength = 6;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts data with the a salted SHA1 algorith. 
    /// The salt will be automatically generated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be encrypted.</param>
    /// <returns>The encrypted data.</returns>
    public ISaltedHash EncryptWithSalt( string value )
    {
        string salt = CreateSalt();

        string hash = Encrypt( salt + value );

        return new SaltedHash
        {
            Hash = hash,
            Salt = salt
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts data with the a salted SHA1 algorith. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be encrypted.</param>
    /// <param name="salt">Salt to be used when encypting the value.</param>
    /// <returns>The encrypted data.</returns>
    public ISaltedHash EncryptWithSalt( string value, string salt )
    {
        string hash = Encrypt( salt + value );

        return new SaltedHash
        {
            Hash = hash,
            Salt = salt
        };
    }

    #endregion // Public Methods

    #region Helper Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates salt.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A base64 salt string.</returns>
    private string CreateSalt()
    {
        byte[] saltBlob = CreateRandomBytes(m_saltLength);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(saltBlob);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts data with the SHA1 algorithm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be encrypted.</param>
    /// <returns>The encrypted data.</returns>
    private string Encrypt( string value )
    {
        byte[] blob = ToByteArray( value );

        byte[] hash = ComputeHash( blob );

        return Convert.ToBase64String( hash );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the hash value for the specified byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="blob">The input to commute the hash for.</param>
    /// <returns>The computed hash code.</returns>
    private byte[] ComputeHash( byte[] blob )
    {
        return new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash( blob );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a UTF8 byte array encoding for the specified character array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The input containing characters to be encoded.</param>
    /// <returns>The UTF8 encoded array.</returns>
    private byte[] ToByteArray( string value )
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( value );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a random byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="length">Length of array to be generated.</param>
    /// <returns>A random byte array.</returns>
    private static byte[] CreateRandomBytes( int length )
    {
        byte[] blob = new byte[length];

        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes( blob );

        return blob;
    }

    #endregion // Helper Methods
}
```

Comment: We normally recommend [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx), bcrypt or scrypt on the site, Justin T. And hashing is not the same as encryption.

Comment: I appreciate hashing and encryption are different, but I think you miss read my post as I was demonstrating an alternative to encryption.

Comment: The problem is more about the method names, they may confuse the reader.

Comment: @owlstead Fair shout, I can see how that would be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please don't give pure code answers, but explain why this piece of code answers the raised question. Refer to [answer]...